# Book recommendation to learn Java for a Perl programmer

Tags: java

I've been programming with Perl for a few years and consider myself proficient. I'm now trying to learn Java and am wondering what would be the best route / resource? Any recommendations on website and/or books would be appreciated. thx.

Comment: Dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102/best-java-book-you-have-read-so-far, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77839/what-are-the-best-resources-for-learning-java-books-websites-etc, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78293/good-book-to-learn-to-program-well-in-java-engineering-or-architecture-wise-not, etc..etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are lots and lots of books; but one that i found really liking is [Thinking in Java](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/).  Note that it's about Java the language, not (so much) about the libraries or environment.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the Java Tutorial.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

If you want a book, go for Head First Java.